# Sample size for prediction model

Tags: predictive-models, small-sample

I am developing a prediction model for prognosis in 90 patients after an intervention. The result is almost 50% were recovered. However, this intervention consists of two different treatments. Since this is not a randomised trial, patients were applied to each treatment depending on the severity of their condition. So if they are severe, go for treatment 1, otherwise 2.
Treatment1 has 48 and 2 has 42 patients and in both 50% were recovered.

Is it ok to put them all into one model or better to separate them?
Since this intervention is one package in a specific setting, the prediction model would be useful only in similar settings with the same intervention. I also don't wanna lose statistical power. But I am worried about the confounding in case putting it all together.

I also want to know the advantages and disadvantages.